# Git URL on Bitbucket returns 404 error

Tags: git, bitbucket

So the raw HTTPS URL for any repo on Bitbucket, e.g. `https://bitbucket.org/user/test.git`, returns 404 error. Is there any reason for this? Why can't I view the raw `.git` document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only raw content associated to a repo would be (if the owner put one) a `README`.

```
https://bitbucket.org/auser/arepo/raw/master/README.md
```

The repo itself has no raw content.